# Minecraft not working on win 10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// There are four lights!

Time: 3/8/16 12:44 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bcf.ap(SourceFile:594)
    at bcf.an(SourceFile:430)
    at bcf.a(SourceFile:377)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bcf.ap(SourceFile:594)
    at bcf.an(SourceFile:430)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bcf.a(SourceFile:377)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.9
    Operating System: Windows 10 (x86) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_73, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 82180336 bytes (78 MB) / 148647936 bytes (141 MB) up to 523501568 bytes (499 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.9
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: No
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Operating system details:
win 10
Ram 4 GB
Java updated

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are affected by the Intel graphics driver issue on Windows 10.

I can see you are running Java r73.  You probably need to downgrade to before r60. You can do this by using the newest Minecraft launcher, msi:
https://minecraft.net/download

The other thing to try is updating your video card driver to the latest version.

More info here:
https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-297

Comment: Why would he need to downgrade Java? Unless the newest versions have a specific bug you know about that interferes with specific program you have in mind you always should use the newest version.

Comment: @Deltharis I've added a link with the bug report